# Magento 2 Modify data on Product Import

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, import

I'm looking for ability to check all data before validation on products import in Magento 2.

I found class `Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Validate` but I can't find entry point to see/check/modify **WHOLE** table (csv file) before it will say `Data validation failed. Please fix the following errors and upload the file again.`

Magento 2.1.4